# In iOS9+, is there a way to move the accessibility focus back to the top when the user reaches the bottom of the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility

I have a `UICollectionViewController` inside of a `UINavigationController`. Ideally, I'd like to put the focus back on the `navigationController` when the user reaches the end of the `collectionview`, so that the user doesn't have to scroll all the way back to the top to get back.

Is there an easy way of accomplishing this? I've tried to explicitly add a `UIBarButtonItem` in the Collection View's accessible elements, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  
  {
     [collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
  }
```

Hope it helps.

However, your approach of scrolling automatically to the Top can annoy users.